# Как отцентрировать содержимое слайда Slick

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Как отцентрировать содержимое слайдов в Slick? Тк, в слайдах у меня текст, он всегда в стороне появляется, добавление `display: flex` ничего не меняет. И единственный вариант, сделать много вложенных `div`-ов, типо этого

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="inside">
            A
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="inside">
            B
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

А хотелось бы ограничиться только `.carousel` и `.slide`

Вот код

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear'
    });
});
```

```css
.content{
 padding: 50px;
}

.slide{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<div class="content">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slide">
                Ab
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
                Cd
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Оформите пример не работающего кода в снипет

Comment: @doox911 Вот код, который я бы хотел, но он не рабоает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ходе моих экспериментов, я нашел 2 пути решения проблемы.

1. Самый простой - добавить `!important` к нужному атрибуту, в моём случае это выглядит так `display: flex!important;`
2. Второй, также простой но не настолько - вы должны иметь `css` файл непосредственно на локальной машине, и подключить его вместо CDN. Дальше вы должны зайти в файл `slick.css` (Или `slick.scss`, как удобно) и на 103 строке (85 в `scss` фале), меняете `display: block` на `flex`.

P.s. Второй вариант лучше использовать когда вам надо сменить это значение на всех слайдерах на сайте

Upd. 3 вариант, спасибо Максиму Талейникову (дайте ему +1, [его сообщение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1117506/300769)). Можно добавить ваш основной css файл после файлов `Slick`-а, и переопределить тот класс, который вам нужен. Но этот вариант потребует понимания работы классов `Slick`-а

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь просто подключить свой файл стилей после стилей библиотеки слика и тогда сможешь переопределить стили, если знаешь как работает специфичность селектора CSS, то получится без труда. Очень не советую бить через !important или лезть исправлять файлы библиотек, очень плохая практика

Comment: Так тоже можно, но когда нужно определить атрибут конкретному блоку не подойдет, также как и мой второй вариант. Но в общем, мне кажется !important более читабельным вариантом